# Apply IHasRequestFilter to Plugin registered service dynamically

Tags: servicestack

I have a set of Services that I want to use in various ServiceStack projects (okay, two) so I have created a ServiceStack Plugin that registers them.

However I want to allow users to determine their own method of securing access to these services.

Currently I have an IHasRequestFilter in one my projects that can determine which services a user should be able to access. I do not want a reference to this in the Plugin project, so I want to add this dynamically after the fact.

I want to somehow get a reference to the Service Definition in AppHost to add this IHasRequestFilter to the pipeline for a specific set of services.

Ideally I should be able to do something like this:

```
new CustomPlugin(new CustomPluginParams {
  RestrictTo = CustomRestrictions,
  RequestFilters = [],
  ResponseFilters = []
});
```

This should use those properties to configure their services without having a previous typed reference.

Edit:

Investigating further it appears that the IHasRequestFilter and IHasResponseFilters are only parsed once, in the `ServiceExec<TService>` class. I could get round this by creating my Services with a Proxy which adds the attribute I require to the MemberInfo of the operations, however I don't regard that as a clean approach.

Does anyone have recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

In ServiceStack all configuration should happen within AppHost's `Configure()` method and remain immutable thereafter.

### Lifecycle Events

To help with LifeCycle events there are `IPreInitPlugin` and `IPostInitPlugin` [Plugin Interfaces](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/IPlugin.cs) which your Plugins can implement so they will get called back before and after all plugins are registered.

There's also an `IAppHost.AfterInitCallbacks` plugins can use to get called back after the entire AppHost has finished initialiazing.

### [Typed Request/Response Filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters#typed-request-filters)

Attributes are typically statically defined on Services, to dynamically add logic that apply to specific Request/Responses you can use a typed Request/Response filter.

The nice thing about ServiceStack Filters is that they share the same API `(IRequest, IResponse, object)` which makes them easily composable, e.g:

```
RegisterTypedRequestFilter<CustomRequest>(new RequestAttributeFilter().Execute);
```

### Dynamically adding Attribute filters

As all ServiceStack libraries use ServiceStack.Text's Reflection API's you're able to extend ServiceStack's attribute-based code-first API [dynamically by adding attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/RuntimeAttributeTests.cs) to types or properties at runtime, e.g:

```
typeof(CustomRequest)
    .AddAttributes(new RuntimeAttributeRequestFilter());
```

This can be done for most of ServiceStack's code-first API's inc. Request/Response Filters.

#### Route attributes and Action Filters

There is sometimes an issue for Services Route attributes and Action filters that already pre-configured and autowired before the AppHost's `Configure()` is called.

One solution is to add them in the AppHost constructor (or by overriding `AppHost.OnBeforeInit`) so they're added before the Services are configured. Otherwise you can reset the action filter caches by calling the AppHost's `ServiceController.ResetServiceExecCachesIfNeeded()`.

Comment: Great answer as always @mythz. I will implement this and report back.